# reading and writing csv file in python corrections

Tags: python, csv

I need some help founding out how to output my code after I have wrote the information to csv file pls could you help do the bit below the if get_bool_input) bit.

filename = class_name + ".csv"

```
with open('filename.csv', 'a',newline='') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    data=[['Name','Score'],
          [name,score]]
    a.writerows()


if get_bool_input("Do you wish to view previous results for your class"):
    print filename
else:
    input ("Press any key to exit")
```

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem your code is experiencing, a description of how you know the code is not working, and an explanation of what you want the code to do instead.

Comment: There are multiple problems in your code not least undefined variables , mixing python 2 and 3 syntax, not using methods correctly or at all in the case of writerows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `a.writerows` to `a.writerows()`.

That should fix it. If it does not, please provide your traceback.